# Use content from label to apply if/else Stylus Css HTML

Tags: html, css, if-statement, stylus

[image: display image of code]

I need apply a style only  whit content "something"

Comment: huh??? why does this look suspiciously like someone with 2 accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how you can do that :

```
<style>
.small {
    color: #000 !important;
}
.small[value^="something"] {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    color: red !important;
}
</style>

<div class="small" value="soething">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div> <!-- Not working -->
<div class="small" value="something">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div> <!-- Working -->
```

It's as simple as that ! :)

Comment: `<div class="small" value="something" style= "color:red;" class="how_to_upvote_myself">`would have been simpler

Comment: Excuse me ? Please feel free to report me then. I don't need to do this in order to up my reputation dude..

Comment: The thing is, I have a lot <small> without the value="something" I want make a global class for all tags <small> only in this case: 
 <small>something</small>  --> Yes
 <small>example</small>  --> No